# Update defaultBranch of build definition via Azure DevOps API

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I need to update the `defaultBranch` of build definition via `Azure API`.

The is the documentation for `PUT` request:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

The problem is that  I don't know the minimum list pf params I need to send in order to create a working request.

I tried to export the actual request from the browser and modify only this field - status code is `200` but nothing was changed. I don't want to pass all filed I just want to modify the `defaultBranch`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the link you provided you have [Request Body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#request-body) section, you can see there what you need to pass. I like to get the definition first (with [Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) API), change what I want, and then perform the update.

In PowerShell:

```
$pat = "YOUR-PAT"
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,"$pat")))
$headers = @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

$url = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}?api-version=5.1"

$build = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -ContentType application/json -Headers $headers

$newDefaultBranch = "test-branch"
$build.repository.defaultBranch = $newDefaultBranch

$json = $build | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Put -ContentType application/json -Headers $headers -Body $json
```

Comment: I've seen the same answer already on StackOverflow. I don't want to transfer data that I really don't need to modify

Comment: @BasilKosovan In the docs of the update definition, you can see in the Request Body that you need all the info.

Comment: Could you please send me a link with an anchor?

Comment: Sorry if I missed smth but I can’t find anything that tell me to send all fields

Comment: @BasilKosovan https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#request-body

Comment: There is no specification that all fields are required

Comment: @Basil Kosovan I am afraid we could not provide mention the properties which are mandatory for updating build definition, there is no any document for each properties. If we want to know that, we may need to test them one by one.  In `Definition-Get` or `Definition-Update` api, we need to specify the `revision` parameter, which could indicate that each time the definition is updated, the old definition is completely replaced with the new definition. In a definition, there will not be only the default branch field.

Comment: @hugh-lin-msft I am passing to 'Put' method the response that I've got from 'Get'(with incremented revision). - response 404. I see that body that is passing in a browser has a few other properties that are not in response from the Get request.

Comment: Are the NuGet package for this?